# Is there any way to get single pixel wide aliased lines?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, freestyle

I'm trying to get clean, one pixel wide lines on my renders like the pic below, but nothing I try seems to work.

[image: The lines I'm trying to get]

I've tried freestyle with one sample, but I get extra pixels at some parts of the strokes and the low sampling makes the rest of the render look really bad.

[image: Freestyle Lines]

I also tried [this compositor nodegroup](https://blendernpr.org/edge-node-v1-2-4-july-2015/) and [this script](https://blenderyard.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/pixelating-freestyle-lines/), but I can't make the nodegroup's lines thin enough and the script just doesn't work at all.

These were the thinnest lines I could get with the nodegroup.

[image: Nodegroup lines]

So is there any way to render lines like the first pic, or am I out of luck?

I'm fine with using either engine.

Comment: Have you set the pixel filter to box (Render Tab > Film) when you're using Cycles?

Comment: Just tried it, [this is what I got](https://imgur.com/gHGTr9k)

Comment: Was just an idea, because that disable anti-aliasing.

Comment: I can get similar results to my second pic by using the other two filter types on the smallest width, but they still aren't as clean as I'd like.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with using the Workbench engine, you can simply go to *User Preferences* → *Viewport* → *Smooth Wires* and disable *Overlay.*
[image]

You can choose the Workbench engine just like Cycles or Eevee in the *Render Properties* tab, and since frames can still be rendered with transparency you could easily composite them into frames rendered with any other engine.
[image]

### Result

[image]